# Overnight bacterial culture

Tags: microbiology

I am working now to prepare an overnight bacterial culture. My question is should i pick only one colony of the bacterium streaked plate in order to make an overnight culture and what will happen if i picked two or three colonies?. I am working to make a deletion mutation in one bacterial starin using the phage transduction method. The technqiue said that i should make an overnight culture in 20 ml of the medium. So, i wondered if it would be two low if i pick only one colony in such amount.

Comment: Broadly the answer is 'yes, work from a single colony' but can you give a few more details of your experiment so that the potential pitfalls can be explained?

Comment: I am working to make a delation mutation in one bacterial starin using the phage transduction method. The technqiue said that i should make an overnight culture in 20 ml of the medium. So, i wondered if it would be two low if i pick only one colony in such amount.